# Get click range relative to parent element

Tags: javascript, dom, range, offset

So I have this problem where I need to get the clicked spot offset relative to the parent element.
Lets assume I have html rendered like that:

```
<div>
   able   to   allocate   many   IPs.
   <span style="background: yellow">
      Proof-of-work   is   essentially   one-CPU-one-vote.
   </span>     The   majority
</div>
```

I want to get the offset of click relative to the parent div. For example if I click the word is in span tags I get the offset of the click relative to the parent Div. How can I implement this.
I have tried to write code like this:

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
var offset = range.startOffset;
```

But this gives me the offset relative to the span tag. So how can I get the offset relative to the div tag?

Comment: Just to be clear... when you say "click" you're not talking about the actual [click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) and it's screen coordinates (`clientX`, `clientY`), correct? You actually mean that you want the offset of the **selected text** relative to the text's parent or grandparent element?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want the offset of the selected text.

Comment: Considering that the end user could click anywhere in your document, how do you know which div node you want the selection to be relative to?

Comment: I would like it to get the closest div to it. I have a pdf file that has text layer rendered on to it. I register onClick event on it. When the div does not have span tag in it I do a series of string analyzing calculations and add the span tag with style to the text layer. Now when the clicked dom element is a span tag I want to get the offset of the clicked spot relative to the spans parentNode. This is needed because I recognise sentences by sentence end mark(?!.)  indexes. So to remove the span tag correctly I need the offset of clicked spot relative to the parentNode,  in my context div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of any built-in functions that can measure the offset of a Range relative to another element. You can use the Range's `startContainer` property and then crawl up and across the DOM hierarchy, measuring the content as you go along.

I created a demo below. Note, however, that this may or may not produce exactly the result you are looking for. For example, this will measure the length of comments and style nodes, and it will count all the space characters, whether or not the browser ultimately renders them. You'll probably need to make adjustments to suit your own purposes by adding checks for the [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) before measuring, pre-collapsing space characters (perhaps using regex replace), etc, but I hope this is a good starting place.

```js
function clicked(){
  console.log( getSelectionOffsetRelativeTo( document.getElementById( 'parent' ) ) );
}

function getSelectionOffsetRelativeTo(parentElement, currentNode){

  var currentSelection, currentRange,
      offset = 0,
      prevSibling,
      nodeContent;
      
  if (!currentNode){
    currentSelection = window.getSelection();
    currentRange = currentSelection.getRangeAt(0);
    currentNode = currentRange.startContainer;
    offset += currentRange.startOffset;
  }
    
  if (currentNode === parentElement){
    return offset;
  }
  
  if (!parentElement.contains(currentNode)){
    return -1;
  }
  
  while ( prevSibling = (prevSibling  || currentNode).previousSibling ){
    nodeContent = prevSibling.innerText || prevSibling.nodeValue || "";
    offset += nodeContent.length;
  }
  
  return offset + getSelectionOffsetRelativeTo( parentElement, currentNode.parentNode );

}
```

```html
Click inside the div:

<div id="parent" style="border: black 1px solid;" onclick="javascript:clicked();">

  Currently in the parent node.

  <span style="color: red;">In the first child span.</span>

  Back in the parent node.

  <span style="color: red;">In the second child span.

    <span style="font-style:italic;">In the grandchild span.</span>

  </span>

  Back in the parent node.

</div>
```